# Angular Material 2 md-input-container not working

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

I'm encountering an issue with angular-material2 where I'm trying to use an input. However, none of what I tried has worked.

I'm getting this issue:

> 'md-input-container' is not a known element

[image: Console issue]

HTML:

```html
<md-input-container>
<input mdInput placeholder="Favorite food" value="Sushi">
</md-input-container>
```

I imported this in my **component.ts** and in my **app.ts**:

```ts
import { MdInputModule } from '@angular/material';
```

and I declared it in my 'imports' in @NgModule in **app.ts**

My version of material is **@angular/material@2.0.0-beta.8**

Thanks for your help.

EDIT : I found that I imported it in the **app.module.ts** which imported another module where I needed to put the declarations. My code is a bit messy, I need to clear it up. Sorry for this my friends. Case closed.

Comment: In which component do you use `md-input-container`?

Comment: Where this component was declared?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import { MdInputModule } from '@angular/material';
```

And  add `MdInputModule` in  `imports:  [ MdInputModule ]` in `@NgModule` in `app.ts`

Comment: -1. Sorry for downvote, but `MaterialModule` shouldn't be used. It's deprecated since [**beta3**](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#200-beta3-cesium-cephalopod-2017-04-07) and it'll probably be completely removed in the next build (`beta9`) once [**this PR**](https://github.com/angular/material2/pull/6581) is merged.

Comment: @developer003 , yes i am aware of that, i should have specified `MdInputModule` earlier as well

Comment: @developer033 Actually, they've deprecated it from `2.0.0-beta.11` onwards (although for some reason it's not released on npm yet...)

Comment: @Edric it's deprecated since Beta 3, you can check the direct link in first comment.

Comment: @developer033 Correction: deprecated -> removed

Answer (score 1):

You should put `MdInputModule` in the import of app.module.ts.
And you should also import every single modules of the Material elements you use

Comment: `import { MdInputModule } from '@angular/material' ` is in my **user-form.component.ts** where I use the the HTML in the **user-form.component.html**. Then it's also declared in the **app.module.ts** and MdInputModule declared into _import_ of the @NgModule as I do for every module I needed before

Answer (score 0):

The way you did it is correct, by importing only the module of the component you use. Importing the whole `MaterialModule` is overkill if you use only one or two components.
What you need to make sure is this (from the [Getting Started guide, step 3](https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started)):

> Whichever approach you use, be sure to import the Angular Material
>   modules after Angular's BrowserModule, as the import order matters for
>   NgModules.

Comment: More than "overkill", the whole `MaterialModule` is about to disappear. Import modules you need, that's it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of md-input-container or mat-input-container, use mat-form-field.
As its the current supported input container as per release version 8.0.0. For more info, see
[official angular material doc](https://material.angular.io/components/input/overview)

Answer (score -2):

Import Material module into your app to access core directives of material

```
import { MaterialModule } from '@angular/material';
```

Comment: How is that different from my answer?

Comment: Don't do this. It's deprecated and it'll be removed soon.

Comment: As for Faisal's answer, don't do this. This module is deprecated and there are plenty of warning about using it for like 2 months.

Comment: @developer033 @Mozgor Actually, they've deprecated it from `2.0.0-beta.11` onwards (although for some reason it's not released on npm yet...)

Comment: @Edric Commented in another answer.